# How to include an additional css file?

Tags: angular

I am using the default 'styles.css' for rendering my webpage.

I have created a separate css file 'printStyles.css' which I pass to printjs(https://www.npmjs.com/package/print-js) as an argument for printing a section of my web page. I have created 'printStyles.css' as I want the style to be different when I print it as a pdf.

I have included the 'printStyles.css' in the assets folder. The  component devlength.component.ts is calling it.

[image]

I do not know how to resolve the following error:

The resource from “http://localhost:4200/assets/printStyles.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: put your prinstStyles.css under the folder "assets" and use `css:'assets/printStyles.css`. In Angular is created severals bundles (main.js,styles.js...) and copy the folder "assets" -that is the adecuate folder to store the static files: .png,.jpge, .json... (the .css is are included in angular.json like styles.css NOT put in assets, but, in your case that you need import is the adecuate place)

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo, I have made the changes, but I still have the  error. I am editing the question to incorporate the changes.